# Java array object if statement to test for equality and calculate payout amount in slot machine

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, constructor

I have to create a slot machine using arrays in Java for an assignment, and I am stuck on the loop to calculate the payout. If there are 2 of the same "face", the payout should be 1, if there are 3 of the same "face", the payout should be 2, if there are 4 of the same "face" the payout should be 3 etc.. So, I have my "faces" stored as an array object and I am stuck on making a loop to check for equality for these objects. I have 2 classes, one for the SlotMachine (there are 2 slot machine objects with different numbers of wheels) Here is my code thus far: Please ignore the graphics part as I just want to get this working in the terminal for now. Thank you for any help in advance!

```
public class SlotMachine {

    public static char Machine1() {

        Wheel[] MachineWheels;
        MachineWheels = new Wheel[5]; // create array of 5 wheels

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            MachineWheels[i] = new Wheel();  // create each actual Wheel with a face
        }

        System.out.println(MachineWheels[0]);
        System.out.println(MachineWheels[1]);
        System.out.println(MachineWheels[2]);
        System.out.println(MachineWheels[3]);
        System.out.println(MachineWheels[4]);

        int payout = 0;

        if (MachineWheels[i] == MachineWheels[i]) {

            payout = 1;
            System.out.println(payout);
        }


            return 0;
    }

public static char Machine2() {

    Wheel[] MachineWheels;
    MachineWheels = new Wheel[7];   // create array of 7 wheels

    for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        MachineWheels[i]= new Wheel();  // create each actual Wheel with a face
    }

    System.out.println(MachineWheels[0]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[1]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[2]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[3]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[4]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[5]);
    System.out.println(MachineWheels[6]);

    return 0;
}


}

import java.util.Random;

    public class Wheel {


    String[] face = {"cat", "dog", "mouse", "cow", "pig", "goat"};

    // Get a random face from the list of options
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(face.length);
    int faceNum = face.length;

    // toString method to return a the randomly chosen face
public String toString() {

    return face[index];
}

}
public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Choose a Machine. Machine 1 has 5 wheels with 6 faces. Machine 2 has 7 wheels with 6 faces." + "\n");
    int message = sc.nextInt();
    switch (message) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Machine 1! (5 wheels, 6 faces)" + "\n");
            System.out.print("Wheels = [cat, cat, cat, cat, cat]" + "\n");
            System.out.print("1 = Spin. 2 = Million Spins. 3 = Quit" + "\n");

            int message2 = sc.nextInt();
            switch (message2) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(SlotMachine.Machine1());



                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.print("Machine 2! (7 wheels, 6 faces)" + "\n");
            System.out.print("Wheels = [cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat]" + "\n");
            System.out.print("1 = Spin. 2 = Million Spins. 3 = Quit" + "\n");

            int message3 = sc.nextInt();
            switch (message3) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(SlotMachine.Machine2());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    break;
        }

        default:

            break;
    }



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterator over your `MachineWheels` array and count the occurrence of each face. An easy way is to use a `Map`. The key would be the face and the value would be the number of occurrences. Then you can pick the value with the highest count and you know your payout.

Comment: Im sorry Im new to programming can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 1):

Have to compute and store somewhere the occurrences. Latter just apply which win-schema may fit. For storage even a `List` can be used with a `customObject(key, counter)`. Using standard loops can generate a solution, but maybe adjusted to stream can increase performance.

```
public class CountWheels 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //after generating the sequence
        String wheels[] = {"a","b","a","a","b"};
        //distinct
        Set<String> set= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(wheels));
        List<WheelsCounter> list = new ArrayList<WheelsCounter>();
        for(String s:set)
        {
            list.add(new WheelsCounter(s));
            for(int i=0;i<wheels.length;i++)
            {
                if(s.equals(wheels[i]))
                {
                    //last added element
                    list.get(list.size()-1).increaseCounter();
                }
            }
        }
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }
    static class WheelsCounter
    {
        private String key;
        private int counter=0;
        WheelsCounter(String key)
        {
            this.key=key;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return "count("+key+")="+counter;
        }
        public void increaseCounter()
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
count(a)=3
count(b)=2
```

Update:

Even if is working, the algorithm is far of being optimal (repeated loops over keys).
Mainly the computation can be done in one loop taking advantage of sorting.(sort increase time also, but overall it's an enhancement)

```
public class CountWheels 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //after generating the sequence
        String wheels[] = {"a","b","c","c","b","b"};
        //ordered sequence
        Arrays.sort(wheels);
        //can be even a set
        List<WheelsCounter> list = new ArrayList<WheelsCounter>();
        String prev=wheels[0];
        for(int i=0,counter=1;i<wheels.length;i++,counter++)
        {
            if(!prev.equals(wheels[i]))
            {
                list.add(new WheelsCounter(wheels[i-1],--counter));
                counter=1;
                prev=wheels[i];
            }
            //last one, add what-ever remain
            if(i==wheels.length-1)
            {
                list.add(new WheelsCounter(wheels[i],counter));
            }
        }
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
                
    }
    static class WheelsCounter
    {
        private String key;
        private int counter=1;

        WheelsCounter(String key, int counter)
        {
            this.key=key;
            this.counter=counter;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return "count("+key+")="+counter;
        }   
    }
}
```

Output

```
count(a)=1
count(b)=3
count(c)=2
```

Note: Using a `Map` can eliminate `sorting` and need just to update on loop the counter. Even so, some time consuming is to find the value associated with key and update the value(counter). Use whatever fits better.